# NGINX server config with Lets Encrypt SSL, HTTP 2, and redirects

Tags: nginx, http2

Recently, I attempted to upgrade my server configs to support HTTP 2 and noticed that when a browser attempted to load the site without SSL, it would instead download a 50 byte binary file.

Configuration is as follows.

It worked as expected - upgrade the request to HTTPS via the redirects - until I added `http2` to the `listen` directives on the redirects at the end.

The fallout is that the unsecured HTTP requests are now cached which super sucks but **I'd like to understand why this happened and how I should be configuring my server**.

I've removed `http2` from the redirects `listen` directives since.

I thought it would be better to specify to the browser that the server supports http2 the whole way but it didn't go as planned - for some reason the response type wasn't being sent as html.

Why has this happened?

```
server {
    root /var/domains/mywebsite.com/html;
    error_log off;
    access_log off;
    index index.php index.html;
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    gzip on;
    gzip_types text/plain application/xml application/json application/javascript;

    location /service-worker.js {
        add_header Cache-Control "max-age=0, no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate";
        expires off;
        access_log off;
    }

    location / {

        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.2-fpm.sock;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    error_log off;
    access_log off;
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;


    location ~ {
            rewrite ^/(.*)$ https://mywebsite.com/$1 permanent;
    }

    listen 443 ssl http2;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mywebsite.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    # include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_ciphers "EECDH+CHACHA20:EECDH+AES128:RSA+AES128:EECDH+AES256:RSA+AES256:EECDH+3DES:RSA+3DES:!MD5";
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    server_name mywebsite.com;

    if ($host = mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80 http2;
    return 404;
}

server {
    server_name www.mywebsite.com;

    if ($host = www.mywebsite.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    listen 80 http2;
    return 404;
}
```

Comment: Not sure why that is happening but every browser requires https to use HTTP/2 anyway so suggest you only turn it on for your 443 config.

Comment: @BarryPollard that's an excellent point! so I wonder if this is a failure on nginx's behalf to recognise that it shouldn't try to send an http2 response

Comment: And that remind me of the bug I'd seen previously!: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/816. Added answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx doesn't allow HTTP/2 and HTTP/1 on non-HTTPS connections. Bug raised here: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/816.

There is little point in non-HTTPS HTTP/2 (aka h2c) connections to be honest as [web browsers only use HTTP/2 over HTTPS](https://caniuse.com/#feat=http2) hence why this bug hasn't been prioritised to be fixed yet.

So remove http2 from your port 80 server config and leave it for your port 443 config.